# how to get information for 30 days in a row?

Tags: sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL Server, I have 3 columns:

```
Server                    State                     Date
SRV1                      True                      2019-01-01
SRV2                      False                     2019-01-01
SRV3                      False                     2019-01-01
SRV4                      True                      2019-01-01
SRV5                      False                     2019-01-01
SRV1                      True                      2019-01-02
SRV2                      True                      2019-01-02
SRV3                      False                     2019-01-02
SRV4                      True                      2019-01-02
SRV5                      False                     2019-01-02
SRV1                      True                      2019-01-03
SRV2                      False                     2019-01-03
SRV3                      False                     2019-01-03
SRV4                      True                      2019-01-03
SRV5                      True                      2019-01-03
```

If a server has a state False for 30 days in a row then I add a column Alive has No :

```
Server                    State                     Date               Alive
SRV1                      True                      2019-01-01         Yes
SRV2                      False                     2019-01-01         Yes
SRV3                      False                     2019-01-01         No
SRV4                      True                      2019-01-01         Yes
SRV5                      False                     2019-01-01         Yes
SRV1                      True                      2019-01-02         Yes
SRV2                      True                      2019-01-02         Yes
SRV3                      False                     2019-01-02         No
SRV4                      True                      2019-01-02         Yes
SRV5                      False                     2019-01-02         Yes
SRV1                      True                      2019-01-03         Yes
SRV2                      False                     2019-01-03         Yes
SRV3                      False                     2019-01-03         No
SRV4                      True                      2019-01-03         Yes
SRV5                      True                      2019-01-03         Yes
```

Here only SRV3 is non active because its state is False in 3 days in a row.

How can I get this output for 30 days in a row ?

Comment: How did you do it for 3 days ? Cant you use the same logic for 30 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this. Please be noted 30 day is fixed and used twice in the query. If wants to apply the same logic on different length of period, you need to change both static number in the script.

```
SELECT *, 
CASE 
    WHEN (
        SELECT COUNT(State) 
        FROM your_table B 
        WHERE B.State = 'False' 
        AND B.Server = A.Server 
        AND (B.Date BETWEEN DATEADD(DD,-30,A.Date)  AND A.Date)
    ) =30 THEN 'No'
    ELSE 'Yes'
END Alive
FROM your_table A
ORDER BY 1,3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it may be help to sort out

```
Declare @Table Table
 (
    [Server] Varchar(30)
    ,[State] varchar(30)
    ,[Date] date
 )

Declare @From_Date date='01jan19'
        ,@To_Date date='03jan19'
        ,@Count int

Set @Count=DATEDIFF(DAY,@From_Date,@To_Date)

 Insert into @Table
 (
    [Server],[State],[Date]
 )

Select 'SRV1','True','20190101'
union all
Select 'SRV1','True','20190102'
union all
Select 'SRV1','True','20190103'
union all
Select 'SRV2','True','20190101'
union all
Select 'SRV2','False','20190102'
union all
Select 'SRV2','True','20190103'

     select [Server]
            ,cast(@From_Date as varchar(15))+' / '+cast(@To_Date as varchar(15)) DateInterval
            , iif(sum(iif([State]='True',1,0))=@Count,'Yes','No') As Alive
       from @Table
   group by [Server]
```